# How to increase speed of file upload using httpwebrequest or webclient?

Tags: c#, performance, file-upload, webclient

I am using webclient.uploadfileasync function to upload a file to server.Using a rest webservice. I tested my internet upload speed and it came out to be 0.3 Mbps.But the upload speed using the webclient came out to be 0.18 Mbps.So, what can I do to increase the upload speed to the actual upload speed to of my internet?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with WebClient and I couldn't find any answer for this problem. But there are other option to solve performance issue. it is to use HttpWebRequest directly.

[Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)